# How can I color all the related rows and columns, rather than just a subset of them (Aspose Cells)?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, aspose, aspose-cells

I had a related question [heretofore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686024/how-can-i-place-my-data-fields-beneath-my-row-field-in-my-pivottable-aspose-cel), and the answer there that (pretty much) works for me is to use:

```
pt.ShowInCompactForm();
```

In a spreadsheet I generate, there are blocks of items that span 5 rows - the first row is a Description, and the four rows below it are "subrows" with detail data for that item (namely, "Total Packages", "Total Purchases", "Sum of Average Price", and "Percentage of Total").

In certain cases, I need to colorize the cells in that region and am able to do this, for the most part, with the following code:

```
private void ColorizeContractItemBlocks(List<string> contractItemDescs)
{
    int FIRST_DESCRIPTION_ROW = 7;
    int DESCRIPTION_COL = 0;
    int ROWS_BETWEEN_DESCRIPTIONS = 5; 
    var pivot = pivotTableSheet.PivotTables[0];
    var dataBodyRange = pivot.DataBodyRange;
    int currentRowBeingExamined = FIRST_DESCRIPTION_ROW;
    int rowsUsed = dataBodyRange.EndRow;

    pivot.RefreshData();
    pivot.CalculateData();

    PivotTable pt = pivotTableSheet.PivotTables[0];
    var style = workBook.CreateStyle();

    // Loop through PivotTable data, colorizing contract items
    while (currentRowBeingExamined < rowsUsed)
    {
        Cell descriptionCell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[currentRowBeingExamined, DESCRIPTION_COL];
        String desc = descriptionCell.Value.ToString();

        if (contractItemDescs.Contains(desc))
        {
            style.BackgroundColor = CONTRACT_ITEM_COLOR;
            style.Pattern = BackgroundType.Solid;

            CellArea columnRange = pt.ColumnRange;
            // Using StartColumn-1 instead of StartColumn-1 gives me the "Percentage of Total" data field subrow (but not the others - "Total Packages", "Total Purchases", and "Sum of Average Price")
            for (int c = columnRange.StartColumn-1; c <= columnRange.EndColumn; c++)
            {
                //pt.Format(currentRowBeingExamined-1, c, style); <= Instead of adding the "Description" row, this colors up some unrelated final ("Percentage of Total") data rows
                pt.Format(currentRowBeingExamined, c, style);
                pt.Format(currentRowBeingExamined + 1, c, style);
                pt.Format(currentRowBeingExamined + 2, c, style);
                pt.Format(currentRowBeingExamined + 3, c, style);
            }

        }
        currentRowBeingExamined = currentRowBeingExamined + ROWS_BETWEEN_DESCRIPTIONS;
    }
}
```

But it only works "for the most part," because I am unable to colorize the "Description" row (such as, "AVOCADOS, HASS 70 CT #2") or any but the last row of column 0/A, - the "Percentage of Total" subrow, as can be seen here:

[image]

It may be that the Description row is better left untainted/unpainted, but I think the subrows beneath would be better off colorized, and I don't understand why they are not.

I can prevent ALL of those subrows from being colored by using this:

```
for (int c = columnRange.StartColumn; c <= columnRange.EndColumn; c++)
```

(that is to say, starting the loop with "StartColumn" instead of "StartColumn-1" prevents anything in column 0/A from being colorized), but it seems bizarre to me that only that last subrow colors up when I start from one column back (at 0/A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will look into your issue in this [Aspose.Cells Forum Thread](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/813681/how-can-i-color-all-the-related-rows-and-columns-rather-than-just-a-subset-of-them.aspx) created by you.

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose